# How to make concurrent api calls in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, api, concurrency, axios

I have the following code:

```
    Promise.resolve(axios.get(`apiwebsite.com/api?tag=${tagsArr[0]}`)),
    Promise.resolve(axios.get(`apiwebsite.com/api?tag=${tagsArr[1]}`)),
    Promise.resolve(axios.get(`apiwebsite.com/api?tag=${tagsArr[2]}`)),
  ]).then((all) => {
    res.json({"success": true, "test": all[0].data}, "test1":all[1].data, "test2":all[2].data);
  });
```

The length of tagsArr is unknown. Therefore, I want to implement some kind of for loop that does an API call for each tags Arr

```
for(let i = 0; i < tagsArr.length; i++) {
        Promise.resolve(axios.get(`apiwebsite.com/api?tag=${tagsArr[i]}`)),
}
```

Now here's where the problem is. I also want my API calls to be concurrent. How can I loop through the tagsArr while making an API call for each tag, while having concurrent API calls?

Comment: minor note: since `axios.get` (like all axios methods) returns a Promise anyway, there is no need for `Promise.resolve` here - it's just creating "noise" in your code so you're better off removing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an array of executed promises and wait for all of them.

```
const promises = tagsArr
    .map(tag => axios.get(`apiwebsite.com/api?tag=${tag}`));

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(responses => {
        // Do your thing here...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put them in array and use Promise.all:

```
Promise.all([
    axios.get(`apiwebsite.com/api?tag=${tagsArr[0]}`),
    axios.get(`apiwebsite.com/api?tag=${tagsArr[1]}`),
    axios.get(`apiwebsite.com/api?tag=${tagsArr[2]}`),
  ]).then((all) => {
    res.json({"success": true, "test": all[0].data}, "test1":all[1].data, "test2":all[2].data);
  });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: the OP explicitly says "The length of tagsArr is unknown" - so this won't work in general, the correct way is to use `tagsArr.map(...)` (as in the other answer)